# Random Forest command in R for selected variables

Tags: r, feature-selection, random-forest, code

All I can find online is how a random forest is run on all variables in a dataset using the period:

`RF <- randomForest(sale ~ ., data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)`

What if I only want to apply the RF to selected variables in the dataset? Would I need to drop the variables first?

I tried the following, but get an error:
`RF <- randomForest(sale ~ v1,v2,v3, data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)`

Comment: Please add the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

`RF <- randomForest(sale ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = TrainSet, importance = TRUE)`

this is the formula notation for R. It doesn't make a lot of sense for random forest models, but it is how it works.